# libpng framework on OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, frameworks, png, libpng

I'm looking for an Xcode project file that will let me trivially build a dynamic framework for libpng to embed in a Mac OS X application bundle.  I found [this project for libpng 1.2.8](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbigzaphod.org%2Fmacosx%2Flibpng%2F&ei=SAqMSoTmMJC2MKGazJMO&usg=AFQjCNEcPyhkKTatQ16xivgAjgMO11yX4Q&sig2=X4uA-YXugvlZZ3Etg5I4Yg), but I need something reasonably current.  I can make the project file myself, but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel if I don't have to.  Does this already exist, and if so, where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [KyngChaos UnixImageIO framework](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software:frameworks).  It includes libpng.

Answer (score 1):

If you download the libpng framework code from http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html it contains an xcode project that builds the framework.